# Returning objects by value?

Tags: c++, oop, return-value

im trying to return a local object from a function

and i have this problem

if i return the locally created object it returns null

```
DString DString :: operator + (const char* param)
{
    // Variable definition
    int nSize = ( this->GetLength() + (strlen(param)));
// Create a new char array in the opropriate size
char* cstrNewString = new char[nSize + 1];

// Append data
strcpy(cstrNewString, this->_cstrString);
strcat(cstrNewString, (char*)param);
cstrNewString[nSize] = '\0';

// Create a new DString to return
DString dstNewData(cstrNewString);

// Clean up
delete[] cstrNewString;

// Return data
return (dstNewData); // Null!
```

if i do the same exact thing only creating a new object in the return line such as this:

```
DString DString :: operator + (const char* param)
{
    // Variable definition


int nSize = ( this->GetLength() + (strlen(param)));

// Create a new char array in the opropriate size
char* cstrNewString = new char[nSize + 1];

// Append data
strcpy(cstrNewString, this->_cstrString);
strcat(cstrNewString, (char*)param);
cstrNewString[nSize] = '\0';

// Create a new DString to return
DString dstNewData(cstrNewString);

// Clean up
delete[] cstrNewString;

// Return data
return (DString(dstNewData.ToCharArray())); // Not null, returns correctly!
```

it returns correctly.. why is it doing this and how can i fix this ?

Comment: I have to ask, what is wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: You need to show us the constructor `DString::DString(char*){}`.Unless you are making a deep copy of the passed character string,what your object gets left with is a dangling pointer since you deallocate the string in next statement.Also, `DString` should obey the **Rule of Three**. Having said that since this is C++ you can save yourself all the above said trouble by using `std::string` and not `char *`.With `std::string` it is hard to go wrong unlike `char *` as you have experienced.

Comment: Is DString your own class?  If so, perhaps there is a problem with the copy constructor, and maybe the copy constructor is elided when used the second way, but not the first.

Comment: Your object must be valid before you return it. My money is on a bad copy ctor.

Comment: And show us the **ToCharArray()** function.

Comment: C++ isn't LISP; you don't need most of those parentheses. For example, change `int nSize = ( this->GetLength() + (strlen(param)));` to `int nSize = GetLength() + strlen(param);`. (Note that I also removed the unnecessary `this->`). All those parentheses just make the code hard to read.

Comment: @Rook "not hungarian enough, and it doesn't even use camelcase, Given that it fails to adhere to these simple standards"  are you serious! that is feature not a bug. Further more it is a shit reason to reinvent the wheel, if you don't like the interface wrap it, don't reimplement. This question is a waste of time

Comment: For all of the annoying people.. I'm not recreating the string class to use, its for practice only -_-, i am used to c# and to c but ive never coded oop in c++ so i thougt a nice way to learn would be to create a string object. thx to the people who helped and written about the copy ctor, as a said i am new to oop in c++ and did not know the importance of such a ctor till now.

Comment: @111111. Dude. Seriously. Despite the obviously facetious nature of my comment I was concerned that my sarcasm wouldn't come through in text, and so I even appended a smiley. Apparently even that isn't enough. I think you need to relax a little, and express your displeasure with flagging, downvoting and constructive commentary as SO is intended to be used.

Comment: @Rook, I wish I could read that as sarcasm, just there are some really backwards people around who legitimately believe that.

Comment: @Pete Becker
Ha ha, i know its a habit i picked up in the army (A C programming course i toke in the army) they had some ugly ass standards that kinda stuck with me. (and you had to use them or you would lose points on tests -_- )

Comment: @DavidLimkys - as my old boss used to say, "There are three ways to do things: the right way, the wrong way, and the army way. And the army way is always right."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is your copy constructor defined?  In the first case, the copy
constructor is called; in the second no.  You don't show us any of the
essential code for `DString`, but given the apparent semantics, it seems
almost certain that the compiler generated copy constructor will *not*
do the right thing.  If you're `DString` contains a dynamically 
allocated pointer (and I don't see how it could be otherwise), which is
deleted in the destructor, the copy constructor must make a deep copy.

Comment: actually, the copy constructor is called both in the first and in the second case!

Comment: As i said in one of the comments I'm new to the way c++ works with objects, i learned C' in the army and my only knowledge of oop is from c#, so i did not know a copy ctor exists or even needed here. thx for the help.

Comment: @Sdra: how? `DString X = DString();`; `operator=` != CopyConstructor

Comment: @Sdra Maybe.  Formally, the copy constructor is called whenever a variable is returned, and there must be one accessible.  Practically, it depends on whether the compiler does NRVO or RVO.  Because he said that he was new to C++, however, it seemed that a missing copy constructor was a likely issue.

Comment: @ted There's no `operator=` in `DString X = DString();`.

Comment: @ted: I don't fully understand your comment (sorry!). however the copy constructor is called after the return statement when the function exits, and that's the case for both functions, since they return by value.

Comment: @ted: BTW, DString X = DString(); call the copy constructor.
X = DString(); calls the assignment operator.

Comment: @Sdra The formal semantics of the language require the copy constructor to be called when returning a value.  The standard also gives the implementation explicit authorization to suppress this copy.  This optimization is called NRVO or RVO (depending on whether you are returning a named variable or a temporary).

Comment: @Sdra: Ok I see, after my wrong assumption I did a bit of reading, thanks for clearing that up/correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you pass by value, implicitly using the (default) constructor (if you didn't define it, `DString::DString(char*)`. In the second case you explicitly calling the constructor, but proabaly a different one (maybe `DString::DString(char const *)`, depends on `dstNewData.ToCharArray()`'s constness). Also please take a look at [Return Value Optimization (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and Scott Meyers Effective C++ item 21 (at the end), since it might add additional confusion due to optimization. Define (and show us) your constructors and the behavior should be more controlled.

It's a wild guess without actually seeing your constructor.

Comment: Where do you see any return of a reference.

Comment: True, it's pass by value, i've misread the code. I think the problem's still the same though, so i'm gonna correct the answer.

Comment: DString::DString(char*) is not a copy constructor!

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:
1) How large are the strings you are copying to cstrNewString and how do you know they fit in cstrNewString?

2) Prefer strncpy() to strcpy() -- with strcpy, you can exceed the size of the array.

3) Why are you using new when you just delete it a few lines later?  I would allocate it on the stack where it is deallocated for free.  (string would be better)

4) cstrNewString[nSize] --> How do you know that the null is being placed at the end of the string?  Is there a gap in between?

Comment: 3) the reason to use `new` is that the size is not known at compile time.

Comment: He calculates the necessary length before allocation.  In this case, I don't think that there's any risk in using `strcpy`.  (On the other hand, you should _never_ use `strncpy`, as it can leave the destination without a `'\0'` terminator.)

Comment: 1) I do not know, that is way i am checking the size.
2) No real reason, just a old habit.
3) Haven't coded in C for a while, i thought it would be good to make myself remember to release the memory myself.
4) Sorry but i did not understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first function does not return NULL but it returns NULL when you call ToCharArray() on the returned object.

This may be related to the fact that you probably did not implemented the Copy constructor, where you should copy the char buffer from the argument object to the *this* object